# Representing a text and color by using a return function in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, return

I'm trying to represent a text with a color in HTML code by using a returning function, however I'm not sure how I can use the returning strings in my function to make the text. It is supposed to be able to change between these two:

```
                    <p class="color-green"><span class="hex">Active</span></p>
                    <p class="color-red"><span class="hex">Frozen</span></p>
                     src='<%= Active_Frozen("text", "color") %>'>
```

Here is the function which I'm planning on implementing:

```
  public Tuple<string,string> Active_Frozen(string text, string color) {

    connection();
    string query = "SELECT CustomerInfo FROM ActiveSubscription WHERE UserName=@UserName";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);


    if (query=="true")
    {
       text = "Active";
       color = "color-green";
    }

    else
    {
       text = "Frozen";
       color= "color-red";
    }

    return Tuple.Create(text, color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the asp:Literal control to handle this:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.text(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.text%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)